# Почему не корректно работают функции JS при изменении ориентации экрана?

Tags: javascript

Дизайнер задумал, что фильтр карточек на десктопе и на мобильном устройстве работает по разному.

На десктопе можно выбрать только одну категорию, при нажатии на кнопку она подсвечивается и отображаются все карточки ее категории.
На мобильном устройстве появляются кнопки применить и отмена, и можно выбрать несколько категорий. При клике по каждой кнопке они подсвечиваются и отображают карточки своих категорий. При повторном клике соответственно скрывают карточки своей категории и перестают светиться.

Я сделал две функции. Вызываю их при разном разрешении экранов, а так же вызываю их при срабатывании события изменения ориентации экрана.

Вопрос: почему при загрузке страницы срабатывает нужный код, в зависимости от разрешения экрана, а при изменении ориентации при клике по кнопкам к карточкам добавляются классы и из одной и из другой функции сразу, а к самим кнопкам класс эктив добавляется только при десктопном разрешении экрана, а на мобильном устройстве не добавляется вообще.

Посмотреть можно по ссылке как работает: https://thesplatt-web.github.io/iceberg-test/portfolio.html

[image: Так выглядит фильтр на десктопе]
[image: Так выглядит фильтр на мобильном устройстве]

HTML

```
<button class="portfolio__btn" type="button" title="Смотреть категорию" data-filter="group1"></button>
<button class="portfolio__btn" type="button" title="Смотреть категорию" data-filter="group2"></button>
<button class="portfolio__btn" type="button" title="Смотреть категорию" data-filter="group3"></button>
<button class="portfolio__btn" type="button" title="Смотреть категорию" data-filter="group4"></button>
<button class="portfolio__btn" type="button" title="Смотреть категорию" data-filter="group5"></button>


<div class="portfolio__item group1"></div>
<div class="portfolio__item group2"></div>
<div class="portfolio__item group3"></div>
<div class="portfolio__item group4"></div>
<div class="portfolio__item group5"></div>
```

JS

```
let sidebarBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio__btn');//Ищем все кнопки
    let casesCard = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio__item');//Ищем все карточки

    let filterCategoriesMobile = function () {//Функция для
        for (let button of sidebarBtn) {//Перебираем все кнопки
            let currentCategory = button.dataset.filter;//Проверяем значение дата-атрибута
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {//Отлавливаем событие клика по кнопке
                button.classList.toggle('active');//Добавляем/удаляем класс active
                let currentCard = document.getElementsByClassName(currentCategory);//Ищем карточки с классом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
                for (let currentCardItem of currentCard) {//Перебираем все карточки с слассом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
                    currentCardItem.classList.toggle('active')//Показываем/скрываем все карточки с классом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
                    for (let card of casesCard) {//Перебираем все карточки
                        let activeCard = document.querySelector('.portfolio__item.active')//Проверяем есть ли на странице хотя бы одна активная карточка
                        if (activeCard) {//Если есть, то скрываем её
                            card.classList.add('hide-mobile')
                        }
                        if (!activeCard) {//Если нет, то не скрываем
                            card.classList.remove('hide-mobile')
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768) {//Вызываем функцию, если ширина окна меньше чем 768 пикселей
        filterCategoriesMobile()
    }

    let filterCategories = function () {//Функция для мобильного устройства
        for (let button of sidebarBtn) {//Перебираем все кнопки
            let currentCategory = button.dataset.filter;//Проверяем значение дата-атрибута
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {//Отлавливаем событие клика по кнопке
                for (let i = 0; i < sidebarBtn.length; i++) {//Удаляем у все кнопок класс active
                    let button = sidebarBtn[i];
                    button.classList.remove('active')
                }
                button.classList.add('active');//Добавляем класс active только выбранной кнопке
                for (let i = 0; i < casesCard.length; i++) {//Скрываем все карточки
                    let card = casesCard[i];
                    card.classList.add('hide')
                    card.ontransitionend = function () {
                        if (card.classList.contains('hide')) {
                            card.classList.add('hidden')
                        }
                    }
                }
                let currentCard = document.getElementsByClassName(currentCategory);//Ищем только карточки содержащие класс равный дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
                for (let currentCardItem of currentCard) {//Показываем только те карточки, которые содержат класс равный дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
                    currentCardItem.classList.remove('hide')
                    currentCardItem.classList.remove('hidden')
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 768) {//Вызываем функцию, если ширина окна больше или равна 768 пикселей
        filterCategories();
    }
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {//Отслеживаем событие изменения ориентации экрана
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768) {//Если ширина экрана больше чем 768 запускаем функцию для десктопа
            filterCategories();
        } else {//Если меньше, то для мобильного
            filterCategoriesMobile();
        }
    });
```

Вопрос так и не решен. Решили отказаться от этой идеи и сделали одинаковую фильтрацию контента на всех устройствах.

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: Переведи вопрос на русский.

Comment: То есть я зря все переводил на английский?) Сейчас изменю вопрос

Comment: Название вопроса - тоже на русский, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я так понял тут в основном подсказывают как правильно оформить вопрос, а не ответ на сам вопрос?)))

Comment: Не надо язвить. На неправильно оформленный вопрос вам ответа точно не дадут.

Comment: Я не язвил, это же шутка)

Comment: Потому что в коде я не увидел ниодного `removeEventListener`

Comment: это не помогло:(

Comment: Что не помогло?

Comment: добавление removeEventListener. Я переписал обе функции, в каждую добавил событие ресайз и проверку на ширину экрана, в одном случае button.addEventListener('click', function), в другом button.removeEventListener('click', function)

Comment: Ну это гениальное решение, заходить в специально ориентированное на русскую аудиторию сообщество и задавать вопрос на английском языке) Аплодирую стоя)

Comment: Я не обратил внимание на какую версию сообщества зашел, так как у меня браузер настроен так, что все англоязычные сайты автоматически переводятся на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

```
const sidebarBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(`portfolio__btn`); //Ищем все кнопки
const casesCard = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio__item');//Ищем все карточки

let isDesktop = document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768;

const onClickMobile = e => {
    const button = e.target;
    let currentCategory = button.dataset.filter;//Проверяем значение дата-атрибута
    button.classList.toggle('active');//Добавляем/удаляем класс active
    let currentCard = document.getElementsByClassName(currentCategory);//Ищем карточки с классом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
    for (let currentCardItem of currentCard) {//Перебираем все карточки с слассом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
        currentCardItem.classList.toggle('active');//Показываем/скрываем все карточки с классом равным дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
        for (let card of casesCard) {//Перебираем все карточки
            let activeCard = document.querySelector('.portfolio__item.active');//Проверяем есть ли на странице хотя бы одна активная карточка
            if (activeCard) {//Если есть, то скрываем её
                card.classList.add('hide-mobile')
            }
            if (!activeCard) {//Если нет, то не скрываем
                card.classList.remove('hide-mobile')
            }
        }
    }
};

const onClickDesktop = e => {
    const button = e.target;
    let currentCategory = button.dataset.filter;//Проверяем значение дата-атрибута
    for (let i = 0; i < sidebarBtn.length; i++) {//Удаляем у все кнопок класс active
        let button = sidebarBtn[i];
        button.classList.remove('active')
    }
    button.classList.add('active');//Добавляем класс active только выбранной кнопке
    for (let i = 0; i < casesCard.length; i++) {//Скрываем все карточки
        let card = casesCard[i];
        card.classList.add('hide');
        card.ontransitionend = function () {
            if (card.classList.contains('hide')) {
                card.classList.add('hidden')
            }
        }
    }
    let currentCard = document.getElementsByClassName(currentCategory);//Ищем только карточки содержащие класс равный дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
    for (let currentCardItem of currentCard) {//Показываем только те карточки, которые содержат класс равный дата-атрибуту активной кнопки
        currentCardItem.classList.remove('hide');
        currentCardItem.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
};


for (let button of sidebarBtn) {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => isDesktop ? onClickDesktop(e) : onClickMobile(e));
}

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
    isDesktop = document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это так же как и у меня не работает:(

Comment: Добавил ссылку где можно посмотреть проблему https://thesplatt-web.github.io/iceberg-test/portfolio.html Обе функции нормально работают, только если при изменении ширины экрана перезагрузить страницу. А так работает корректно только функция которая вызвалась при загрузке страницы.